# How to get past the pond in the cave?

Tags: limbo

See this screenshot:

[image: Pond with dead children]

I suspected that I had to go back and grab the rope:

[image: Depressing rope]

But I cannot reach it.

Can you give me a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it. You have to jump onto the dead ... children.

[image]

Comment: AGH!! I don't think I'll be able to sleep tonight.

Comment: @Alex: I'm sorry for that, but I couldn't get the image into a spoiler container. But I give you this, Limbo *is* pretty disturbing.

Comment: yeah, I got it recently but haven't reached this point yet. I hope my brain manages to block it out before then!